# Sql Server Analysis Services won't start after reboot

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Had to restart a server running SQL Server and SQL Server Analysis Services. (The reboot was related to the Hyper-V Host it was running on.)
The SQL service works fine, but the SSAS refuses to start.

Checking the log and Event Viewer, the following is displayed:

> The service cannot be started: Message-handling subsystem: The message
>   manager for the default locale cannot be found. The locale will be
>   changed to US English. Message-handling subsystem: The message manager
>   for the default locale cannot be found. The locale will be changed to
>   US English. (Source: \?\E:\ASLOG\XXX\msmdsrv.log, Type: 3, Category:
>   289, Event ID: 0xC1210000)

When changing the locale settings for the account running the SSAS service to "EN-US" and trying to start the service again, it gives me a blank error message in both Event Viewer and the SSAS log...

> The service cannot be started:  (Source: \?\E:\ASLOG\XXX\msmdsrv.log,
>   Type: 3, Category: 289, Event ID: 0xC1210000)

Any ideas?

Comment: What was the reason for the reboot?

Comment: The reboot was related to the Hyper-V Host it was running on, but should affect the SQL-server at all.
The problem still exists..